# Unable to map a string value passed in Terraform with text value in Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, terraform, user-data

I am trying to pass AWS EC2 Userdata in Jenkins as a variable.
Source code is in terraform, main.tf as shown below:

```
userdata = var.web_userdata`
variables.tf:
`variable "web_userdata" {
  type = string
  default = <<EOF
 <powershell> net user Administrator '12345' 
 Copy-S3Object -BucketName test-bucket -KeyPrefix Test -LocalFolder C:\PS_automation -Force
 &"C:\PS_automation\Master1.ps1"
 </powershell> 
 <persist>false</persist>
 EOF
}
```

Jenkins File:

```
text (name: 'web_userdata', defaultValue: '<powershell>\n net user Administrator "12345" \nCopy-S3Object -BucketName test-bucket -KeyPrefix Test -LocalFolder C:/PS_automation -Force \n &"C:/PS_automation/Master1.ps1" \n</powershell> \n<persist>false</persist>', description:'user data for ec2')
```

But when I try to crate the servers, the user data section is blank and I get the below:

```
`/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CC_INFRA_TERRAFORM_WEBSERVER@tmp/durable-dbc94db9/script.sh: line 1: web_userdata: command not found
+ terraform plan -var Infrastructure_region=eu-west-1 -var VPC_Name=VPC -var 'Subnet_Name=*Subnet*' -var Security_Group_Name=sg -var Web_instance_type=t2.medium -var instance_count=2 -var instance_name=Test -var 'ebs_size=["10"]' -var AMI_ID=ami-017661010558cc954 -var Root_EBS_Size=30 -var Root_EBS_Type=gp3 -var ebs_vol_type=gp3 -var ebs_count=1 -var web_userdata= `
```

Can someone help with a solution here

Comment: You don't need to specify the user data variable with `-var` when calling `terraform plan` as it has a default value.

Comment: The root cause here is in the `Jenkinsfile`, but you have not shared the relevant code so that we could assist.